# Gem compatibility and Ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to find out which gems need to be updated in a Rails app if the Ruby version is upgraded?

For example, I would like to know which of my Rails app gems will have to be upgraded if I upgrade my Ruby from 2.1.3 to 2.2.2. The preference would be to keep the changes minimal as to reduce the probability of things breaking.

The important thing would be for this to be a dry-run. So that one can assess the amount of work that an upgrade will require.

I have checked *bundle* and *gem* readme's without much luck.

Comment: You can usually find the required ruby version in the `.gemspec` files, like [this one](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/rails_admin.gemspec#L30) for example. Is that the kind of thing you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks Paul! Yes, that's pretty close to what I'm looking for. Is there a gem or other tool to automate that process? I guess I can write my own script, but if there is an easier way out there that would be nice. Given the number of gems in a Rails app Gemfile, it would be very time consuming to manually check every single gem to see which Ruby versions they are compatible with.

Comment: Unfortunately, if there is something like that out there, I have no clue about it. In a perfect world, you would update the ruby version locally, rebundle, and run all your tests to see if anything fails (and hopefully the tests are complete enough to cover all the bases). Barring that, the best I can think of is to take a look at only the gems you've placed in the Gemfile yourself. I also wouldn't be too worried about a small version increase like that. Ruby 2 to 3 would be a bigger, potentially breaking, leap, but 2.1 to 2.2 shouldn't do much if anything to interfere with an existing system.

Comment: Yes, I wish the perfect world scenario worked. But it turns out that just enough things have changed from 2.1 to 2.2, and other gems have changed also, that the "just update Ruby and bundle install" process hasn't worked out. It sounds like that I may have to write my own script that checks the `.gemspec` files. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you update your rails version, it should install or resolve the required dependencies needed to run the new rails version. As far as as the gems you have entered that are NOT dependencys to Rails, you can check gem compatibility on rubygems.org. Just type in the title of your gem in the search bar.

Comment: Thanks Jimi! Those are both great ideas, but we are trying to avoid updating Rails just yet, as that _will_ break things. The manual checking process is what we are trying avoid, but it wouldn't be the end of the world, I guess. Automated is always nicer though.